# What does this code wrapping in brackets do within a class atributte?

Tags: jquery, html

This is the first time I have seen this code:

```
 <div id="extruderLeft" class="{title:'Our network ', url:'parts/extruderLeft.html'}"></div>
 <div id="extruderLeft1" class="a {title:'Leyenda', url:'parts/extruderLeft1.html'}"></div>
```

Is a jquery Plugin,  I´m sure that is a HTML constructor, the plugin is called here:

```
<script>
 $("#extruderLeft1").buildMbExtruder({
                position:"left",
                width:300,
                extruderOpacity:.8,
                onExtOpen:function(){},
                onExtContentLoad:function(){},
                onExtClose:function(){}
            });
</script>
```

Is it good practice?

Thank you very much!

Comment: I doubt that HTML5 allows anything but CSS class names in the `class` attribute.

Comment: @Tomalak: CSS has nothing to do with HTML. Class names are a property of HTML, not CSS. See also http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18701670/can-i-use-non-existing-css-classes/18701712#18701712 That being said, it's clear that the class attribute is being misused here.

Comment: @BoltClock I hesitated to say something like "space separated name tokens", so I used a more colloquial term. I would have expected that something like this would not validate, but I've just checked and it does. So it's purely a semantical error, not a technical one.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you are specifying an example of [jquery.mb.extruder](https://github.com/pupunzi/jquery.mb.extruder) plugin, You should go through its [**official docs**](https://github.com/pupunzi/jquery.mb.extruder/wiki#html-constructor), it is HTML constructor.

Comment: Yes, I´m sure that is a HTML constructor, but this is the first time I have seen a constructor inner a `class` atributte.  Is it good practice?

Comment: @RP_morales, According to me its complete misuse of class attribute. developers should have used custom `data-*` attibutes.