# class have background image or not

Tags: javascript, css

I have a list of class names. I want to know which class has background image. how can I do that using javascript.

Suppose I have classes in css

```
.class1 {
   background-image = url("someurl");
   some attributes
}
.class2 {
   some attributes
}
```

I have only array of class name

```
arr = ["class1", "class2"]
```

Here is code what I am doing in javascript

```
element  = document.getElementsByTagName('*');
for(var i = 0; i < element.length; i++){
   var C = element[i].className;
   var arr = C.split(' '); //because an element can have more classes and any of them can have background image
   for(var j = 0; j < arr.length; j++){
      var clas = arr[j];
      // here I want something that can find clas has background image or not
   }
}
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Why do you want to know? This sounds like an XY problem ( http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem )

Comment: You want to find out which classes, in the stylesheet, have background-images set? Or which classes, of the elements on the page, have background-images set?

Comment: @David which classes, of the elements on the page, have background-images set

Answer (score 1):

Though it really seems its an XY problem for you, but still you can know which class has a `background-image` set.
see http://jsfiddle.net/z3uLt1ea/,

```
$(function(){
   arr = ["class1", "class2"];
    arrBgExists=[];
    $(arr).each(function(i,ele){

        var exists=$('.'+ele).css('background-image');
        console.log(exists)
        if(exists!='none'){
            arrBgExists.push(ele);
        }

    });

console.log('these elements are having background'+arrBgExists);    
})
```

I have used Jquery here( [and here is the pure javascript version](http://jsfiddle.net/z3uLt1ea/2/)).

**Please Note**: css classes are actually html classes(I mean they are defined when you create an html element with that class) read [this answer from BoltClock](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18701712/3556874),

so my solution is only valid when you have defined elements **with** classes you want to find out([example situation](http://jsfiddle.net/z3uLt1ea/1/)), else there is no solution

Comment: @RohitKumar.. added the javascript only solution

Comment: @RohitKumar: have you considered accepting the answer